# Polyphonic C# methods separated by ampersand?

Tags: c#, polyphonic-c#

I'm reading [this introduction to Polyphonic C#](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nick/polyphony/intro.htm) and the first page contains this example:

> **Example: A Simple Buffer**
>
> Here is the simplest interesting example of a Polyphonic C# class:
>
> ```
> public class Buffer {
>     public String get() & public async put(String s) {
>         return s;    
>     } 
> }
> ```

I don't get it at all.
What does the `&` between methods `get()` and `put()` signify?

Comment: @Amy: I assume that OP has mixed both languages, probably like many others. So i would keep th C# tag even if it's misleading. Just because this question could  resolve this misunderstanding.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Agreed, I read it as regular C#, thus my confusion, better keep the C# tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not legal C#. That's polyphonic C#. That's a [research project from Microsoft](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nick/polyphony/). It's a shame it's not precisely defined<sup>1</sup> but the point is this:

> In Polyphonic C#, however, a body may be associated with a set of (synchronous and/or asynchronous) methods. We call such a definition a chord, and a particular method may appear in the header of several chords. The body of a chord can only execute once all the methods in its header have been called.

So `&` is "binding" those methods together into a chord which won't be invoked until all the methods in the chord are invoked.

A little further along in the same [article](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nick/polyphony/intro.htm):

> These two methods appear (separated by an ampersand) in the header of a single chord, the body of which consists of the return statement.
>   Now assume that `b` is an instance of `Buffer` and that producer and consumer threads wish to communicate via `b`. Producers make calls to `put()`, which, since the method is asynchronous, do not block. Consumers make calls to `get()`, which, since the method is synchronous, will block until or unless there is a matching call to put(). **Once `b` has received both a `put()` and a `get()`, the body runs and the argument to the `put()` is returned as the result of the call to `get()`.** Multiple calls to `get()` may be pending before a `put()` is received to reawaken one of them and multiple calls to `put()` may be made before their arguments are consumed by subsequent `get()`s.

<sup>1</sup>: But, such is the nature of cutting edge. I do get it.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply the syntax for specifying multiple methods that make up a chord. The body will not execute until all methods in the header are called.

Comment: So it's Polyphonic C# specific, not from regular C# ?

Comment: Yes, this is Polyphonic specific.